# How to Update Country via a dropdown?

Tags: magento-1.7

Is there any way to update country via a dropdown (same as currency in the header)

So that when the customer goes to the basket, that the correct country is already selected?

Comment: What do you mean? You are talking about the checkout not the basket, I think? And where comes this information from?

Comment: Yes in the Cart/Checkout there is a country option in the estimate shipping and tax... I want to be able to set this country sidewide. So when the customer goes to the checkout, the right country and options for that country are showing

Answer (score 1):

## Answer to your question (nearly the same as beneath)

Have a look on the template:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml:37
<?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
```

There is the method `\Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping::getEstimateCountryId`

```
public function getEstimateCountryId()
{
    return $this->getAddress()->getCountryId();
}
```

So two ways: rewrite the block and put your logic in or inject your address somewhow.

```
public function getAddress()
{
    if (empty($this->_address)) {
        $this->_address = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    }
    return $this->_address;
}
```

And by somehow I mean: implement an observer and set the shipping address on the quote.

## Answer to another Question:

I try to answer the question.

The country-dropdown is built here (for onepage checkout):

```
\Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract::getCountryHtmlSelect()
```

The value is set: `->setValue($countryId)`

and country id comes from here:

```
$countryId = $this->getAddress()->getCountryId();
if (is_null($countryId)) {
    $countryId = Mage::helper('core')->getDefaultCountry();
}
```

More digging is up to you. You can rewrite the block, you can have a look on the `$this->getAddress()` to set the countryId or have a look on the `Mage_Core_Helper_Data` what the default country is and maybe set this:

```
public function getDefaultCountry($store = null)
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_COUNTRY, $store);
}
```

A tip in the end: You have two real options: just rewrite the Onepage_Billing Block. This is the easy way or hack somehow the \Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing::getAddress() method to inject somehow the address. But this sounds a bit hacky to me.

Comment: answer edited..