# Where to find the select html tag for countries on the checkout page

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout

Where can I the html **select** tag for countries on the checkout page?

```
<div class="field form-group">
       <label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
       <div class="input-box">
          <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
       </div>
</div>
```

with this `$this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing')`, it returns the html select tag below,

```
<select name="billing[country_id]" id="billing:country_id" class="validate-select" title="Country" >
<option value="" > </option>
<option value="AF" >Afghanistan</option><option value="AL" >Albania</option>
<option value="DZ" >Algeria</option>
...
```

But I need to **add a class name** to the `select` tag,

```
class="form-control validate-select"
```

But where can I find this `select` tag?

Comment: Possibly related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/how-to-update-country-via-a-dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The country select box is prepared by the block,

To change its behavior you just need override the function to you local folder like below.

Just copy the `core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Billing.php` to you local folder like

`local\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Billing.php`

Now you just need to put the below code in that file see I have added the "form-control" to `setClass()` function.

its done now your class will be added to the select box.

```
public function getCountryHtmlSelect($type)
{
    $countryId = $this->getAddress()->getCountryId();
    if (is_null($countryId)) {
        $countryId = Mage::helper('core')->getDefaultCountry();
    }
    $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
        ->setName($type.'[country_id]')
        ->setId($type.':country_id')
        ->setTitle(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Country'))
        ->setClass('validate-select form-control')
        ->setValue($countryId)
        ->setOptions($this->getCountryOptions());
    if ($type === 'shipping') {
        $select->setExtraParams('onchange="if(window.shipping)shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);"');
    }

    return $select->getHtml();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Almost the same as your other question: [How to set default shipping method and country?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19607/how-to-set-default-shipping-method-and-country/)

Try replacing:

```
<?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
```

With this:

```
<?php $_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(false) ?>
<?php if (count($_countries) > 0): ?>
    <select name="billing[country_id]" id="billing:country_id" class="validate-select">
        <option value="">Please choose a country...</option>
        <?php foreach($_countries as $_country): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>">
                <?php echo $_country['label'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then all you need to do is add classes to `<select name="billing[country_id]" id="billing:country_id" class="validate-select">`

Comment: Worked perfectly - no need to overwrite core files or create new - spot on!